# infimum over a space-dependent family of concave functions

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis

I am currently studying the concavity of the following function
$$
g(x)=\inf_{z\in Z(x)} f(x,z),
$$
where for each $z$, $x\to f(x,z)$ is a  concave function, locally bounded uniformly in $z$, and $Z(x)$ is a non-empty compact set at each $x$.

If $Z$ is independent of $x$, then it is clear that $g$ is concave in $x$. I was wondering whether there is any existing result asserting that under certain assumptions of $Z$ (maybe regularity under certain metric), $g$ is concave?

Comment: There are not many concave functions that are bounded below...

Comment: @copper.hat sorry for the misleading, I just want to assume local boundedness such that the infremum is well-defined.